# How can I install Internet Explorer 32bit in Windows 64bit?

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, 32-bit, internet-explorer-9

I have laptop with Windows 7 professional 64 bit.

Straight after installation, I removed all software I was not going to use, including Internet Explorer.

Now I need to use IE, and what's more - I need to use IE in 32bit version.

I did download IE 9.0 32 bit for windows 7 installer, but when trying to install it, I get window with:

```
Wrong version of Internet Explorer installer
This version of setup doesn't support your Windows system type (32-bit/64-bit).
```

It could be that I removed some things that now cause the problem. What can I do now, to get the 32bit IE?

Comment: The 32-bit version of Internet Explorer is already installed by default on all versions of Windows.  If you removed Internet Explorer all you need to do is install Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Download the 64 Bit version of IE 9 and install it.  After install, look at your All Programs menu and you'll see right under Internet Explorer (64-bit), "Internet Explorer" That is the 32-bit version.  It installs alongside the 64bit version

Answer (score 0):

Install internet explorer from microsoft website, install it and "Run" this:

```
%systemdrive%\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe
```